# How to convert String to list in java8 using ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have a JSON String called `primarySkillStr` :

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "roleIds": [
      2
    ],
    "rating": 2
  }

]
```

I try to map it to an object as follows:

```
primarySkillList = mapper.readValue(primarySkillStr, 
    new TypeReference<List<PrimarySkillDTO>>() {});
```

But when Iam converting this to a `List` then the `roleIds` List is `null`.
Am I doing something wrong, or is there any other way?

This is my DTO

```
public class PrimarySkillDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer rating;
    private List<Integer> roleIds;
    private String name;
}
```

I have the following annotations in the `PrimarySkillDTO` class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

Comment: seems to work here: [PrimarySkillDTO(id=3, roleIds=[2], rating=2)] - how does your DTO look like?

Comment: How does java8 relate to this question at all? Isn't it just Jackson?

Comment: @Nick-vanderhoven Added DTO

Comment: everything is private, what else do you have in the DTO? Do you have getters?

Comment: with your DTO + getters, the result is [PrimarySkillDTO(id=3, rating=2, roleIds=[2], name=null)]

Comment: it looks like something is wrong with the accessors, maybe the name of the getter or something?

Comment: I have @Data  annotations in DTO

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your `JsonNaming` annotation requires snake_case and you are not using it.

**To solve it**

- remove the annotation `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)`
- or, rename the variable in the JSON String to `role_ids`

Comment: OK.I got it.Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 3):

SnakeCaseStrategy will map roleIds <--> role_ids, The following codes work for me:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeReference<List<TestClass>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<TestClass>>() {};

List<TestClass> testList = objectMapper.readValue(testStringObject, typeRef);
```